# Calling get method using linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call the following get method in web api but I am currently experiencing an compiling error -  'bool' does not contain a definition for 'password' and no extension method 'password' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) -- error

User class:

```
 public class User : iUser
  {
    private cdwEntities db;

    public User()
    {
        db = new cdwEntities();
    }

    public User(cdwEntities context)
    {
        db = context;
    }


    public bool Validate(string username, string password)
    {

        var query = from t in db.Trial_Try
                    join u in db.UserDetails on t.tUID equals u.uID
                    where t.tExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                    t.tPublication.Value == 163 &&
                    u.uUsername == username &&
                    u.uPassword == password
                    select u; //

        // "execute" the query
        return query.FirstOrDefault() != null; 

    }
```

Test class:

```
  public HttpResponseMessage GetValidate(string username, string password)
    {
        User layer = new User();

        var result = layer.Validate(username, password);

        ***if (result.username != null && result.password != null)***
        {

            var mes = string.Format("Success");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, mes);
        }
        else
        {
            //var mis = string.Format("User {0} not found");
            //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, mis, result);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate is returning a Boolean, not the result of the query. As @ekad stated, check result as a Boolean directly.

As an additional optimization, consider using .Any instead of FirstOrDefault since you don't need the hydrated result and can optimize the SQL to an Exists query rather than select top 1. Your validate method could then be:

```
public bool Validate(string username, string password)
{

    var query = from t in db.Trial_Try
                join u in db.UserDetails on t.tUID equals u.uID
                where t.tExpiryDate >= DateTime.Now &&
                t.tPublication.Value == 163 &&
                u.uUsername == username &&
                u.uPassword == password
                select u; //

    // "execute" the query
    return query.Any(); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `result` is a `bool` and it doesn't have `username` or `password` property, so you need to replace this line

```
if (result.username != null && result.password != null)
```

with this

```
if (result)
```